# Parse custom element using adaptive card sdk in iOS

Tags: ios, parsing, sdk, adaptive-cards, extensibility

Want to write a deserialize method for parsing the new property in adaptive card using the adaptive card SDK  at the iOS client.
Example :

```
{

  "type": "AdaptiveCard",

  "appId": "",

  "new_property ": {},

  "body": [],

  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",

  "version": "1.2"

}
```

Consider "new_property" as the custom element of adaptive card and I want to write my own deserialize method for parsing this.

Approaches tried :

```
ACRRegistration *registration = [ACRRegistration getInstance];
[registration setCustomElementParser:[[New_propertyParser alloc] init] key:@"new_property"];
```

But this is not working and I also added a deserialize method to this parser class but control is not reaching there.